# Get files of certain extension c#

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems, getfiles

I wish to get a list of all the files of a certain extension (recursive), but **only** the files ending with that extension.

For example, I wish to get all the files with the ".exe" extension, If I have the following files:

> file1.exe , file2.txt.exe , file3.exe.txt , file4.txt.exe1 , file5.txt

I expect to get a list of 1 file, which is: `file1.exe`.

I'm trying to use the following line:

```
List<string> theList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SearchDir", "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

But what I get is a list of the following three files: `file1.exe , file2.txt.exe , file4.txt.exe1`

Any ideas?

Comment: Should `123.567.exe` match??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var exeFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, 
                                        "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
               .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") && s.Count( c => c == '.') == 2)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Sie whats the source directory

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue to see. Take note to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern, such as "*.txt", the matching behavior when the extension is exactly three characters long is different than when the extension is more or less than three characters long. **A searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters** returns files having an extension of **three or more characters, where the first three characters match the file extension specified in the searchPattern.**

You can't solve it by searching for the `.exe` extension; you'll need to filter your results one more time in the client code.

Now, one thing to note also is this. The following examples would in fact be considered *executable* files:

```
file1.exe
file2.txt.exe
```

whereas this one wouldn't technically be considered an *executable* file.

```
file4.txt.exe1
```

So the question then becomes, what algorithm do you want? It appears to me you want the following:

- Files that have an extension of `exe`.
- Files that don't have *multiple* extensions.

Have a look at Ahmed's answer for a fantastic approach to getting the algorithm you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. I did use Ahmed's approach, and it works like a charm.